# Azure error: Failed to swap web app slots: There was an error processing your request

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I apparently can't swap the slots for my Azure Web App.

This is critical for me, because I can't release a new version to fix issues on our platform.

The Azure Portal doesn't give me any further info.

Anyone has this before? Any workarounds?

[image: Failed_to_swap]

Comment: I had this for a while. Sometimes it seemed to work from 'the other' portal. They are probably both calling the same endpoint really. but when I had this issue in the old portal, trying again from the new portal sometimes got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is urgent for you, here's a workaround: you can create a new Web App so that you have separate endpoints to deploy Staging and Production. Make sure you update any custom domain entries so that your users can get to the correct URL each time.

To troubleshoot further, contact Azure Support ASAP to let them know that your slots aren't swapping for some reason. If you find the issue, please comment below in case it is helpful to others as well.

All the best!